# Merge two associative PHP arrays with different keys

Tags: php, arrays, merge, associative-array

Imagine two associative arrays:

```
$array1= array(
        array('date'=>'1-Sep-2016', 'price1'=>98),
        array('date'=>'1-Oct-2016', 'price1'=>77),
        array('date'=>'1-Nov-2016', 'price1'=>87),
        array('date'=>'1-Dec-2016', 'price1'=>88),
        array('date'=>'1-Jan-2017', 'price1'=>91)
        );

$array2= array(
        array('date'=>'1-Feb-2016', 'price2'=>98),
        array('date'=>'1-Mar-2016', 'price2'=>77),
        array('date'=>'1-Apr-2016', 'price2'=>87),
        array('date'=>'1-May-2016', 'price2'=>88),
        array('date'=>'1-Jun-2016', 'price2'=>91),
        array('date'=>'1-Jul-2016', 'price2'=>88),
        array('date'=>'1-Aug-2016', 'price2'=>88),
        array('date'=>'1-Sep-2016', 'price2'=>88),
        array('date'=>'1-Oct-2016', 'price2'=>88)
        );
```

The merged array should look like:

```
$merged =array(
        array('date'=>'1-Feb-2016', 'price2'=>98),
        array('date'=>'1-Mar-2016', 'price2'=>77),
        array('date'=>'1-Apr-2016', 'price2'=>87),
        array('date'=>'1-May-2016', 'price2'=>88),
        array('date'=>'1-Jun-2016', 'price2'=>91),
        array('date'=>'1-Jul-2016', 'price2'=>88),
        array('date'=>'1-Aug-2016', 'price2'=>88),
        array('date'=>'1-Sep-2016', 'price1'=>98, 'price2'=>88),
        array('date'=>'1-Oct-2016', 'price1'=>77, price2'=>88),
        array('date'=>'1-Nov-2016', 'price1'=>87),
        array('date'=>'1-Dec-2016', 'price1'=>88),
        array('date'=>'1-Jan-2017', 'price1'=>91)
};
```

Note below lines:

```
  array('date'=>'1-Sep-2016', 'price1'=>98, 'price2'=>88),
  array('date'=>'1-Oct-2016', 'price1'=>77, price2'=>88),
```

In short:
I need to merge combine two arrays without removing any element from either array. `Array1` will always contain `date` and `price1` elements while `array2` will always contain `date` and `price2` elements. So if both array contain the same date (example: `1-Sep-2016`) the result array (`merged`) need to have them them merged by adding `price1` and `price2` elements as well. I hope you got my point (sorry, not a native English speaker) :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php array\_merge associative arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233721/php-array-merge-associative-arrays)

Comment: @Script47 Appreciate your suggestion. However, I've not been able to use the post you suggested. Neither answer helped me to get array combined the way I explained.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using the date as a key in your merged array.

```
$i = 1;
foreach (array($array1, $array2) as $array) { 
    foreach ($array as $entry) {
        $key = strtotime($entry['date']); // convert to a timestamp so it will be sortable
        $new_array[$key]['date'] = $entry['date'];
        $new_array[$key]["price$i"] = $entry["price$i"];
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Then if you want the results to be sorted, you can use

```
ksort($new_array);
```

Comment: Hahaha! best nick name ever! __+1 for you