# Is array_merge perform reindexing?

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

Suppose I have an associative array with keys that are alphabetic string, and if I merge something to this array, It will merge successfully without reindexing like

```
$arr1 = array('john'=>'JOHN', 'marry'=>'Marry');
$arr1 = array_merge(array('78'=>'Angela'),$arr1);
print_r($arr1);
```

then this will correctly merge new component to array and its output will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Angela
    [john] => JOHN
    [marry] => Marry
)
```

But when I tried same thing like this

```
 $arr1 = array('34'=>'JOHN', '04'=>'Marry');
 $arr1 = array_merge(array('78'=>'Angela'),$arr1);
 print_r($arr1);
```

then its output is like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Angela
    [1] => JOHN
    [04] => Marry
)
```

Can anyone describes this scenario.....
Also I want my array to be like this after merging..

```
Array
    (
        [78] => Angela
        [34] => JOHN
        [04] => Marry
    )
```

How can I Achieve that??

Comment: `print_r($arr1+$arr2);` -  https://eval.in/780732

Comment: Thanks for your reply @splash58.....but can you describe why array_merge is not doing that?

Comment: Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array. - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: `04` is regarded as a string index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php array\_merge associative arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233721/php-array-merge-associative-arrays)

Answer (score 2):

as per definition [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) will reindex numeric indexes. a string with a numeric value is also a numeric index.

To prevent this behaviour concatenate the arrays using $arr1+$arr2

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `array_merge()` as you can simply add the arrays:

```
$arr1 = [
  '10' => 'Angela',
  'john' => 'JOHN',
  'marry' => 'Marry',
];

$arr2 = [
  '78' => 'Angela'
];

$arr3 = $arr2 + $arr1;
```

> *[array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)* - ... values in the input array with numeric keys will be ***renumbered*** with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.